# How to link Bootstrap Tabs Dropdown list to URL

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My dropdown list within the Twitter Bootstrap tab is not doing anything when I click it. I have searched for possible solutions on Stackoverflow but they still did not work for me. I removed the data-toggle='tab' already.

FYI - I'm using Twitter Bootstrap 3.0

See code below:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs case-detail-nav" id="myTab">
   <li class="dropdown">
   <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="#">Text Files<b class="caret"></b></a>
   <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
     <li><a href='http://www.google.com/'>google</a></li>
   </ul>
   </li>
   <li class="active"><a href="#general">General</a></li>
 </ul>
```

See Javascript:

```
<script>
  $(function () {
    $('#myTab a:last').tab('show')
  })


  $('#myTab a').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  $(this).tab('show')
})  
</script>
```

Much appreciated!

Comment: Bind event on DOM ready.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is `preventDefault` on anchor click, which you dont want to do for the one in the dropdown . So do a check before preventing default. `preventDefault()` will prevent the default behavior of anchor and when you try to show `$(this).tab('show')` bootstrap will take the href as a selector to select the element to display as tab (which will cause error as well in jquery sizzle due to invalid chars in the selector).

```
 $('#myTab a').click(function (e) {
     if (!$(this).closest('.dropdown-menu').length) { //check if this is from dropdown
         e.preventDefault();
         $(this).tab('show');
     }
 });
```

or just target only for the real tab triggers.

```
$('#myTab > li > a').click(function (e) {
         e.preventDefault();
         $(this).tab('show');
 });
```

Comment: Great explanation. Straight forward and to the point! Thanks.

Comment: @alchuang You are welcome. By the way i have added another option as well... Try that.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else who stumbles across this with a similar issue...

I had the same issue, but in my case removing the data-toggle attribute resolved the issue:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="http://www.gavinharriss.com/" target="_blank" data-toggle="collapse">Some link</a></li>
</ul>
```

becomes

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="http://www.gavinharriss.com/" target="_blank">Some link</a></li>
</ul>
```